# Navigate between multiples User Controls in one form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a form and multiple controls.

Say I have a single form and it should contain some controls.

I'm trying to work with a single form and add and remove controls depending on some use cases.

For example, this is a sample code in my form class:

```
private void AddToControlPanel(UserControl control)
        {
            this.panelControl.Controls.Add(control);
            this.panelControl.Tag = control;
            this.panelControl.Size = control.Size;
            this.panelControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            control.Show();
        }
```

Above sample adds a control to some panel and shows it.

Problem is I can't manage to add some other control and drop current one. For example, if some login control authenticates successfully, drop login control itself and show other like a search box control.

How can achieve that?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
if (LoginOK)
{
   //Add the next Control I want to load
   this.ParentForm.Controls.Add(new CtlPedirDevolucion());
   //Remove this actual control
   this.ParentForm.Controls.Remove(this);
}
```

... so later show latest added control using an event handler:

```
private void FirstForm_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls[this.Controls.Count - 1].Show();
}
```

But this isn't working for me. In addition I don't like my approach.

Will you suggest me a better way of achieving this please?

Comment: Have you tried to switch the two calls in a way that you first remove the control and then add the new one? Or you could maybe create a method in your Form ( which you can easily find using FindForm method) that switches the Controls that are passed as parameters.

Comment: mm how will be that ? I mean, I thought on something in the form, that receives a Control in the form after close another one, so can create it, but I didn't know how to do that. I will search something about FindForm()

Comment: There's no point in calling Show(), a control automatically becomes visible when you add it to the parent's Controls collection.  So scratch the code you don't like.  Just one bad bug, calling Remove() is a very nasty leak.  You **must** use Dispose() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant But he maybe wants to retain some controls live in his code and than put them back in the Panel, although it is not the best approach, I can imagine that maybe this is the case.

Comment: @ElVieejo I've edited your question in order to let others understand you better!

Comment: @ElVieejo Ah, SO is an English-oriented site so next time refactor member names in English (this time I've done it for you!).

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer sorry about that, I forgot it. And thanks for the comments about dispose and Show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried something similar and it works.

Code in your Form:

```
public void SwitchControls(Control removeCtrl, Control addControl)
{
     panel1.Controls.Remove(removeCtrl);
     panel1.Controls.Add(addControl);
}
```

Code in your Control:

```
MyForm frm = (MyForm)this.FindForm();
CtlPedirDevolucion newCtrl = new CtlPedirDevolucion();
newCtrl.Dosck = DockStyle.Fill;
frm.SwitchControls(this, newCtrl);
```

**EDIT:** My bad, there is no point creating a  CtlPedirDevolucion in control that will be removed. It should be instantiated in your Form and there should also be a reference to it. Therefore SwitchControls should have a more complex logic, and maybe more parameters but this is something you can work with. Maybe you could make a switch-case or something that will create a control within your form. I remind you that this is just an example that works but is very bad.